# Excel If Statement date range Late,OnTime and Open

Tags: excel, if-statement

`=IF(Q2>P2 +30,"Late","")` how would I get a returned value "Open"if cell Q2 is empty and "OnTime" if Q2 less than P2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to nest some your `If` statements.

What you have is something like (pseudo-code):

```
   If Q2 > P2 + 30 Then "Late"
   Else If Q2 <= P2 + 30 Then "On Time"
   Else If Q2 = Empty Then "Open"
```

An `If` statement, whether formula or in VBA/code, consists of:

`If(expression, true_part, false_part)`

You can nest them, by putting another `If` statement in the `false_part` (or any other equation you might need).

For example, you could mimic the `ABS` function by something like:

```
If(A1>=0,A1,-1*A1)
```

So in the above example you can see how we might use an *equation* or formula in the `false_part` in order to do some additional transformation. In your case, the formula will just be another `If` statement to evaluate.  Something like:

```
If(Q2>P2+30,"Late",If(Q2<=P2+30,"On Time",If(Q2="","Open","")))
```

For simplicity, I would probably do it like:

```
If(Q2="","Open",IF(Q2<=P2+30,"On Time","Late"))
```

This way, you're first checking to make sure Q2 is empty/not empty, and only testing against Q2/P2+30 once.  It's just a shorter equation but it does the same thing.